# How can I return xml without <string> element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am using `XML` serialization in my project. It's working good but I am facing two issues.

1. Formatting of nodes
2. Remove `<string></string>` from response

Sample object which I am trying to serialize is :

```
[XmlRoot("result")]
public class SwRequestListModel
{
    public SwRequestListModel()
    {
        SwRequest = new List<SwRequestShortInfo>();
    }

    [XmlElement("api_version")]
    public string ApiVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sw_request")]
    public List<SwRequestShortInfo> SwRequest { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sw_request_short_info")]
public class SwRequestShortInfo
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sw_ref_number")]
    public string SwRefNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "db_no")]
    public string DbNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "engine_manufacturing_no")]
    public string EngineManufacturingNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "engine_ref_type")]
    public string EngineRefType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "raised_date")]
    public string RaisedDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "raised_by")]
    public string RaisedBy { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "approved_by")]
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "system_type")]
    public string SystemType { get; set; }
}
```

The code which I am using to serialize is :

```
public static string ToXml(SwRequestListModel obj)
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        NewLineOnAttributes = true,
        NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
        IndentChars = Environment.NewLine
    };
    using (var sww = new StringWriter())
    {            
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, settings))
        {                
            s.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            return sww.ToString(); 
        }
    }        
}
```

Response is display like :

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><result> <api_version>1.0</api_version> <sw_request> <sw_ref_number>588</sw_ref_number> <db_no>99899</db_no> <engine_manufacturing_no>MF99899</engine_manufacturing_no> <engine_ref_type>X40B</engine_ref_type> <raised_date>22/06/2021</raised_date> <raised_by>Srusti.Thakkar@test.com</raised_by> <status>Requested</status> <approved_by /> <system_type>test</system_type> </sw_request> <sw_request> <sw_ref_number>589</sw_ref_number> <db_no>88552</db_no> <engine_manufacturing_no>MF99899</engine_manufacturing_no> <engine_ref_type>X40B</engine_ref_type> <raised_date>22/06/2021</raised_date> <raised_by>Srusti.Thakkar@test.com</raised_by> <status>Requested</status> <approved_by /> <system_type>UNIC</system_type> </sw_request> <sw_request> <sw_ref_number>590</sw_ref_number> <db_no>33899</db_no> <engine_manufacturing_no>MF99899</engine_manufacturing_no> <engine_ref_type>X40B</engine_ref_type> <raised_date>22/06/2021</raised_date> <raised_by>Srusti.Thakkar@test.com</raised_by> <status>Requested</status> <approved_by /> <system_type>UNIC</system_type> </sw_request> </result></string>
```

Actual API Method is :

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetRequestList(string date, string status, string systemType)
    {        
        SwRequestListModel result = new SwRequestListModel();
        result.ApiVersion = "1.0";
        
        //Here get data 

        return result.ToXml();
    }
```

Browser result is :
[image: Like this image]

Update :

[image: XML output be like]

[image: Actual result is this]

Comment: Could you please share with us the xml output as text, not as a picture?

Comment: It's already there

Comment: Sorry I've missed that lengthy line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess API method `GetRequestList` serialize string object. Try to return raw string.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetRequestList(string date, string status, string systemType)
    {        
        SwRequestListModel result = new SwRequestListModel();
        result.ApiVersion = "1.0";

        //Here get data           

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(result.ToXml());
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: It's working but this is displaying like row, not like xml. I had attached result as image please check.

Comment: Try to add MediaType: "application/xml" to StringContent:  

`response.Content = new StringContent(result.ToXml(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");`